# Google Analytics v4 Measurement Protocol - how to send tech and acquisition data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4, apple-appclips

#### Background:

I am tracking acquisition data to a mobile application. Certain links redirect to App Store or Google Play store through my website, where Google Analytics collects data on those redirects.

The mobile application also utilizes a new iOS feature called "App Clips", which basically an app fragment that just opens without user needing to go through store download. When the app clip launches, the "middleman" redirecting website is never opened.

In order to have coherent data on Android and iOS acquisition, I wanted to collect the `page_view` event via Measurement Protocol, triggered directly from the "App Clip".

#### Problem:

The GA v4 Measurement Protocol API is in alpha. The `page_view` event is actually missing from the docs, but it can be sent nonetheless.

I want to understand how to populate the event parameters in the request in order to send data required in "Tech" and "Acquisition" categories. This means at least user-agent data, exact device model, campaign, medium and source.

```json
{
    "client_id": "<what_goes_here?>",
    "timestamp_micros": "1627192577008000",
    "non_personalized_ads": false,
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "params": {
                "page_title": "App Clip",
                "language": "en-us",
                "page_location": "https://example.com/x?utm_campaign=my_campaign",
                "screen_resolution": "1170x2532",
                //"page_referrer": ""
                "page_path": "/x?utm_campaign=my_campaign"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I do not want to use Firebase SDK inside the App Clip for two reasons:

1. I want the App Clip to be lightweight and Apple discourages usage of 3rd party libraries
2. I could not be assured that sending `screen_view` will render the same analytical depth (the same parameters) as `page_view`.

Comment: GA4 doesn't have page_views or screen_views it only has events.   GA4 its completely different from universal analytics and firebase analytics.

Comment: GA v4 has events names page_view and screen_view, see example code above and GA UI.

Comment: Same question, but for web app which is uses server-side tracking (to hide from tracker blockers analytics data behind custom domain). What we did – we linked GA4 property to BigQuery (with Daily exports option). In custom events we are setting up custom `user_properties` for app name, os name, os version, browser name, etc. Then we can analyse results in BigQuery using those custom `user_properties`. At the end tech data, demographics, etc. is blank on analytics website. But who cares if we have custom counterparts for those data.

Answer (score 3):

The client ID refers to the google client ID generated by the gtag script on the frontend side.

Assume for example you have a tag manager or just added an analytics tag to your website. This generates a cookie on the browser (by default is is named `_ga_<ID>` - where the ID can be retrieved when setting up your analytics property. *Note: you can easily customize the name of the cookie*). This cookie includes the client ID. When you communicate to your backend API to trigger events, you need to forward this value, either directly by including cookies in your API calls, or by reading the cookie via JS (which is not HttpOnly) and sending the value along with other params.

The cookie value looks like `GS1.2.163179xxxx.18.0.163179xxxx.0`

Then extract the client ID and add it to your payload.

In our ruby/rails code we extract the client ID with

```rb
google_analytics_client_id = context[:controller].request.cookies[Settings.google_analytics_prefix]&.split('.')&.last(2)&.join('.')
```

then you can send it to the measurement protocol. Our code looks like

```rb
def event_payload(user:, event_name:, google_analytics_client_id:, event_params: {}, event_time:)
  {
    user_id: user.id.to_s,
    timestamp_micros: (event_time.to_f * 1_000_000).to_i,
    non_personalized_ads: false,
    user_properties: {
      your_property: { value: user.some_property },
    },
    client_id: google_analytics_client_id,
    events: [
      { name: event_name }.tap do |h|
        h[:params] = event_params if event_params.any?
      end,
    ],
  }
end
```

I'm not 100% sure this is working since we seem to have problems on our side (it does create events for users, but they do not get UTM attribution correctly for instance), but maybe it has to do with [the limitations](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/limitations)